# Sphinx: New indexes not showing up in SHOW TABLES

Tags: configuration, full-text-search, sphinx

I have a Sphinx configuration that has been working splendidly with a single index and source. I've since added 5 new indexes and sources to the configuration file, and running the indexer produces the following output:

```
Sphinx 2.1.7-release (r4638)
Copyright (c) 2001-2014, Andrew Aksyonoff
Copyright (c) 2008-2014, Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)

using config file 'c:\development\applicationdb\tools\sphinx_config\sphinx.windows.
conf'...
indexing index 'title_autocomplete_idx'...
collected 59915 docs, 2.0 MB
sorted 1.3 Mhits, 100.0% done
total 59915 docs, 2012851 bytes
total 0.881 sec, 2284197 bytes/sec, 67991.97 docs/sec
indexing index 'artist_autocomplete_idx'...
collected 5487 docs, 0.1 MB
sorted 0.1 Mhits, 100.0% done
total 5487 docs, 99775 bytes
total 0.096 sec, 1039041 bytes/sec, 57140.77 docs/sec
indexing index 'author_autocomplete_idx'...
collected 569 docs, 0.0 MB
sorted 0.0 Mhits, 100.0% done
total 569 docs, 11804 bytes
total 0.046 sec, 255249 bytes/sec, 12304.03 docs/sec
indexing index 'subject_autocomplete_idx'...
collected 3367 docs, 0.1 MB
sorted 0.0 Mhits, 100.0% done
total 3367 docs, 55260 bytes
total 0.075 sec, 728063 bytes/sec, 44361.00 docs/sec
indexing index 'publication_autocomplete_idx'...
collected 651 docs, 0.0 MB
sorted 0.0 Mhits, 100.0% done
total 651 docs, 41883 bytes
total 0.060 sec, 687429 bytes/sec, 10684.91 docs/sec
indexing index 'content_idx'...
collected 59915 docs, 7.8 MB
sorted 1.0 Mhits, 100.0% done
total 59915 docs, 7763023 bytes
total 5.762 sec, 1347099 bytes/sec, 10396.91 docs/sec
total 12 reads, 0.014 sec, 1207.3 kb/call avg, 1.2 msec/call avg
total 99 writes, 0.037 sec, 397.5 kb/call avg, 0.3 msec/call avg
rotating indices: successfully sent SIGHUP to searchd (pid=2000).
```

When I connect to the Sphinx service and make queries against any index besides content_idx, I get local index not found errors.

Running Show Tables;

```
mysql> show tables;
+-------------+-------+
| Index       | Type  |
+-------------+-------+
| content_idx | local |
+-------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Why are my new indexes not available to query?

Here's my config file (long!!)

```
#############################################################################
## data source definition
#############################################################################

source base_src
{
    type                            = mysql

    sql_host                        = localhost
    sql_user                        = <nope>
    sql_pass                        = <nope>
    sql_db                          = applicationdb_normalized
    sql_port                        = 3306  # optional, default is 3306
    sql_ranged_throttle = 0

    sql_query_pre = SET NAMES 'utf8';
}

source content_search : base_src
{
    sql_query                       = SELECT \
    \
    c.id as content_id, \
    c.title, \
    c.year_published_min, \
    c.year_published_max, \
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(a.first_name,' ',a.last_name) SEPARATOR ", ") as artist_name, \
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(a.first_name,' ',auth.last_name) SEPARATOR ", ") as author_name, \
    cp.name as container_publication_name, \
    sm.name as subject_matter, \
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT k.word SEPARATOR ", ") as keyword \
    \
    FROM content c \
    LEFT JOIN content_artist ca ON c.id = ca.content_id \
    LEFT JOIN artist a ON ca.artist_id = a.id \
    LEFT JOIN container_publication cp ON c.container_publication_id = cp.id \
    LEFT JOIN container_publication_author cpa ON cp.id = cpa.container_publication_id \
    LEFT JOIN author auth ON cpa.author_id = auth.id \
    LEFT JOIN content_subject_matter csm ON c.id = csm.content_id \
    LEFT JOIN subject_matter sm ON csm.subject_matter_id = sm.id \
    LEFT JOIN content_keyword ck ON c.id = ck.content_id \
    LEFT JOIN keyword k ON ck.keyword_id = k.id \
    \
    GROUP BY content_id \

    sql_field_string = title
    sql_field_string = artist_name
    sql_field_string = container_publication_name
    sql_field_string = author_name
    sql_field_string = keyword
    sql_field_string = subject_matter
    sql_attr_bigint = year_published_min
    sql_attr_bigint = year_published_max
}

source title_autocomplete : base_src
{
    sql_query = SELECT id,title FROM content
    sql_field_string = title
}

source artist_autocomplete : base_src
{
    sql_query = SELECT id,CONCAT(last_name, ', ', first_name) AS artist_name FROM artist
    sql_field_string = artist_name
}

source author_autocomplete : base_src
{
    sql_query = SELECT id,CONCAT(last_name, ', ', first_name) AS author_name FROM author
    sql_field_string = author_name
}

source publication_autocomplete : base_src
{
    sql_query = SELECT id,name FROM container_publication
    sql_field_string = name
}

source subject_autocomplete : base_src
{
    sql_query = SELECT id,name FROM subject_matter
    sql_field_string = name
}

#############################################################################
## index definition
#############################################################################

index title_autocomplete_idx
{
    source = title_autocomplete
    path = C:\wamp\apps\sphinx-2.1.7-release-win32\data\title_autocomplete_idx
    docinfo = extern
    charset_type = utf-8
    min_word_len = 3
    enable_star = 1
    min_prefix_len = 3
}

index artist_autocomplete_idx
{
    source = artist_autocomplete
    path = C:\wamp\apps\sphinx-2.1.7-release-win32\data\artist_autocomplete_idx
    docinfo = extern
    charset_type = utf-8
    min_word_len = 3
    enable_star = 1
    min_prefix_len = 3
}

index author_autocomplete_idx
{
    source = author_autocomplete
    path = C:\wamp\apps\sphinx-2.1.7-release-win32\data\author_autocomplete_idx
    docinfo = extern
    charset_type = utf-8
    min_word_len = 3
    enable_star = 1
    min_prefix_len = 3
}

index subject_autocomplete_idx
{
    source = subject_autocomplete
    path = C:\wamp\apps\sphinx-2.1.7-release-win32\data\subject_autocomplete_idx
    docinfo = extern
    charset_type = utf-8
    min_word_len = 3
    enable_star = 1
    min_prefix_len = 3
}

index publication_autocomplete_idx
{
    source = publication_autocomplete
    path = C:\wamp\apps\sphinx-2.1.7-release-win32\data\publication_autocomplete_idx
    docinfo = extern
    charset_type = utf-8
    min_word_len = 3
    enable_star = 1
    min_prefix_len = 3
}

index content_idx
{
        source                      = content_search
        type                        = plain
        rt_mem_limit                = 32M
        path                        = C:\wamp\apps\sphinx-2.1.7-release-win32\data\content_idx
        charset_type                = utf-8
        morphology                  = stem_en
        min_word_len                = 3
        preopen                     = 1
        charset_table = 0..9, a..z, _, A..Z->a..z, U+00C0->a, U+00C1->a,\
        U+00C2->a, U+00C3->a, U+00C4->a, U+00C5->a, U+00C7->c, U+00C8->e,\
        U+00C9->e, U+00CA->e, U+00CB->e, U+00CC->i, U+00CD->i, U+00CE->i,\
        U+00CF->i, U+00D1->n, U+00D2->o, U+00D3->o, U+00D4->o, U+00D5->o,\
        U+00D6->o, U+00D8->o, U+00D9->u, U+00DA->u, U+00DB->u, U+00DC->u,\
        U+00DD->y, U+00E0->a, U+00E1->a, U+00E2->a, U+00E3->a, U+00E4->a,\
        U+00E5->a, U+00E7->c, U+00E8->e, U+00E9->e, U+00EA->e, U+00EB->e,\
        U+00EC->i, U+00ED->i, U+00EE->i, U+00EF->i, U+00F1->n, U+00F2->o,\
        U+00F3->o, U+00F4->o, U+00F5->o, U+00F6->o, U+00F8->o, U+00F9->u,\
        U+00FA->u, U+00FB->u, U+00FC->u, U+00FD->y, U+00FF->y, U+0100->a,\
        U+0101->a, U+0102->a, U+0103->a, U+0104->a, U+0105->a, U+0106->c,\
        U+0107->c, U+0108->c, U+0109->c, U+010A->c, U+010B->c, U+010C->c,\
        U+010D->c, U+010E->d, U+010F->d, U+0112->e, U+0113->e, U+0114->e,\
        U+0115->e, U+0116->e, U+0117->e, U+0118->e, U+0119->e, U+011A->e,\
        U+011B->e, U+011C->g, U+011D->g, U+011E->g, U+011F->g, U+0120->g,\
        U+0121->g, U+0122->g, U+0123->g, U+0124->h, U+0125->h, U+0128->i,\
        U+0129->i, U+0131->i, U+012A->i, U+012B->i, U+012C->i, U+012D->i,\
        U+012E->i, U+012F->i, U+0130->i, U+0134->j, U+0135->j, U+0136->k,\
        U+0137->k, U+0139->l, U+013A->l, U+013B->l, U+013C->l, U+013D->l,\
        U+013E->l, U+0141->l, U+0142->l, U+0143->n, U+0144->n, U+0145->n,\
        U+0146->n, U+0147->n, U+0148->n, U+014C->o, U+014D->o, U+014E->o,\
        U+014F->o, U+0150->o, U+0151->o, U+0154->r, U+0155->r, U+0156->r,\
        U+0157->r, U+0158->r, U+0159->r, U+015A->s, U+015B->s, U+015C->s,\
        U+015D->s, U+015E->s, U+015F->s, U+0160->s, U+0161->s, U+0162->t,\
        U+0163->t, U+0164->t, U+0165->t, U+0168->u, U+0169->u, U+016A->u,\
        U+016B->u, U+016C->u, U+016D->u, U+016E->u, U+016F->u, U+0170->u,\
        U+0171->u, U+0172->u, U+0173->u, U+0174->w, U+0175->w, U+0176->y,\
        U+0177->y, U+0178->y, U+0179->z, U+017A->z, U+017B->z, U+017C->z,\
        U+017D->z, U+017E->z, U+01A0->o, U+01A1->o, U+01AF->u, U+01B0->u,\
        U+01CD->a, U+01CE->a, U+01CF->i, U+01D0->i, U+01D1->o, U+01D2->o,\
        U+01D3->u, U+01D4->u, U+01D5->u, U+01D6->u, U+01D7->u, U+01D8->u,\
        U+01D9->u, U+01DA->u, U+01DB->u, U+01DC->u, U+01DE->a, U+01DF->a,\
        U+01E0->a, U+01E1->a, U+01E6->g, U+01E7->g, U+01E8->k, U+01E9->k,\
        U+01EA->o, U+01EB->o, U+01EC->o, U+01ED->o, U+01F0->j, U+01F4->g,\
        U+01F5->g, U+01F8->n, U+01F9->n, U+01FA->a, U+01FB->a, U+0200->a,\
        U+0201->a, U+0202->a, U+0203->a, U+0204->e, U+0205->e, U+0206->e,\
        U+0207->e, U+0208->i, U+0209->i, U+020A->i, U+020B->i, U+020C->o,\
        U+020D->o, U+020E->o, U+020F->o, U+0210->r, U+0211->r, U+0212->r,\
        U+0213->r, U+0214->u, U+0215->u, U+0216->u, U+0217->u, U+0218->s,\
        U+0219->s, U+021A->t, U+021B->t, U+021E->h, U+021F->h, U+0226->a,\
        U+0227->a, U+0228->e, U+0229->e, U+022A->o, U+022B->o, U+022C->o,\
        U+022D->o, U+022E->o, U+022F->o, U+0230->o, U+0231->o, U+0232->y,\
        U+0233->y, U+1E00->a, U+1E01->a, U+1E02->b, U+1E03->b, U+1E04->b,\
        U+1E05->b, U+1E06->b, U+1E07->b, U+1E08->c, U+1E09->c, U+1E0A->d,\
        U+1E0B->d, U+1E0C->d, U+1E0D->d, U+1E0E->d, U+1E0F->d, U+1E10->d,\
        U+1E11->d, U+1E12->d, U+1E13->d, U+1E14->e, U+1E15->e, U+1E16->e,\
        U+1E17->e, U+1E18->e, U+1E19->e, U+1E1A->e, U+1E1B->e, U+1E1C->e,\
        U+1E1D->e, U+1E1E->f, U+1E1F->f, U+1E20->g, U+1E21->g, U+1E22->h,\
        U+1E23->h, U+1E24->h, U+1E25->h, U+1E26->h, U+1E27->h, U+1E28->h,\
        U+1E29->h, U+1E2A->h, U+1E2B->h, U+1E2C->i, U+1E2D->i, U+1E2E->i,\
        U+1E2F->i, U+1E30->k, U+1E31->k, U+1E32->k, U+1E33->k, U+1E34->k,\
        U+1E35->k, U+1E36->l, U+1E37->l, U+1E38->l, U+1E39->l, U+1E3A->l,\
        U+1E3B->l, U+1E3C->l, U+1E3D->l, U+1E3E->m, U+1E3F->m, U+1E40->m,\
        U+1E41->m, U+1E42->m, U+1E43->m, U+1E44->n, U+1E45->n, U+1E46->n,\
        U+1E47->n, U+1E48->n, U+1E49->n, U+1E4A->n, U+1E4B->n, U+1E4C->o,\
        U+1E4D->o, U+1E4E->o, U+1E4F->o, U+1E50->o, U+1E51->o, U+1E52->o,\
        U+1E53->o, U+1E54->p, U+1E55->p, U+1E56->p, U+1E57->p, U+1E58->r,\
        U+1E59->r, U+1E5A->r, U+1E5B->r, U+1E5C->r, U+1E5D->r, U+1E5E->r,\
        U+1E5F->r, U+1E60->s, U+1E61->s, U+1E62->s, U+1E63->s, U+1E64->s,\
        U+1E65->s, U+1E66->s, U+1E67->s, U+1E68->s, U+1E69->s, U+1E6A->t,\
        U+1E6B->t, U+1E6C->t, U+1E6D->t, U+1E6E->t, U+1E6F->t, U+1E70->t,\
        U+1E71->t, U+1E72->u, U+1E73->u, U+1E74->u, U+1E75->u, U+1E76->u,\
        U+1E77->u, U+1E78->u, U+1E79->u, U+1E7A->u, U+1E7B->u, U+1E7C->v,\
        U+1E7D->v, U+1E7E->v, U+1E7F->v, U+1E80->w, U+1E81->w, U+1E82->w,\
        U+1E83->w, U+1E84->w, U+1E85->w, U+1E86->w, U+1E87->w, U+1E88->w,\
        U+1E89->w, U+1E8A->x, U+1E8B->x, U+1E8C->x, U+1E8D->x, U+1E8E->y,\
        U+1E8F->y, U+1E96->h, U+1E97->t, U+1E98->w, U+1E99->y, U+1EA0->a,\
        U+1EA1->a, U+1EA2->a, U+1EA3->a, U+1EA4->a, U+1EA5->a, U+1EA6->a,\
        U+1EA7->a, U+1EA8->a, U+1EA9->a, U+1EAA->a, U+1EAB->a, U+1EAC->a,\
        U+1EAD->a, U+1EAE->a, U+1EAF->a, U+1EB0->a, U+1EB1->a, U+1EB2->a,\
        U+1EB3->a, U+1EB4->a, U+1EB5->a, U+1EB6->a, U+1EB7->a, U+1EB8->e,\
        U+1EB9->e, U+1EBA->e, U+1EBB->e, U+1EBC->e, U+1EBD->e, U+1EBE->e,\
        U+1EBF->e, U+1EC0->e, U+1EC1->e, U+1EC2->e, U+1EC3->e, U+1EC4->e,\
        U+1EC5->e, U+1EC6->e, U+1EC7->e, U+1EC8->i, U+1EC9->i, U+1ECA->i,\
        U+1ECB->i, U+1ECC->o, U+1ECD->o, U+1ECE->o, U+1ECF->o, U+1ED0->o,\
        U+1ED1->o, U+1ED2->o, U+1ED3->o, U+1ED4->o, U+1ED5->o, U+1ED6->o,\
        U+1ED7->o, U+1ED8->o, U+1ED9->o, U+1EDA->o, U+1EDB->o, U+1EDC->o,\
        U+1EDD->o, U+1EDE->o, U+1EDF->o, U+1EE0->o, U+1EE1->o, U+1EE2->o,\
        U+1EE3->o, U+1EE4->u, U+1EE5->u, U+1EE6->u, U+1EE7->u, U+1EE8->u,\
        U+1EE9->u, U+1EEA->u, U+1EEB->u, U+1EEC->u, U+1EED->u, U+1EEE->u,\
        U+1EEF->u, U+1EF0->u, U+1EF1->u, U+1EF2->y, U+1EF3->y, U+1EF4->y,\
        U+1EF5->y, U+1EF6->y, U+1EF7->y, U+1EF8->y, U+1EF9->y
}

#############################################################################
## indexer definition
#############################################################################

indexer
{
    mem_limit                       = 256M
    write_buffer                    = 8M
}

#############################################################################
## searchd settings
#############################################################################

searchd
{
    listen                          = 9312
    listen                          = 9306:mysql41
    log                             = C:\wamp\logs\sphinx\searchd.log
    query_log                       = C:\wamp\logs\sphinx\query.log
    read_timeout                    = 5
    client_timeout                  = 300
    max_children                    = 30
    persistent_connections_limit    = 30
    pid_file                        = C:\wamp\logs\sphinx\searchd.pid
    max_matches                     = 1000
    seamless_rotate                 = 1
    preopen_indexes                 = 1
    unlink_old                      = 1
    mva_updates_pool                = 1M
    max_packet_size                 = 8M
    max_filters                     = 256
    max_filter_values               = 4096
    max_batch_queries               = 32
    workers                         = threads # for RT to work
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Indexer output just show it did send the rotate signal to searchd, however it may be possible searchd to not load them for some reason. Check searchd.log to see what searchd says there.

Comment: I had forgotten about that log, I will check it.

Answer (score 0):

Many sphinx versions (I don't know which ones exactly) dont actully load brand **new** indexes during a reload (which is what --rotate does) :(

Try actully stopping and starting the sphinx searchd service.

Comment: Last line of the indexer output: "rotating indices: successfully sent SIGHUP to searchd (pid=2000)."

It definitely has rotated. (I didn't show the command I used to run the indexer, my bad.).